# What is the time complexity of below program?

Tags: c++, loops, time-complexity, big-o

Below is the program which find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters, given a string str. ([details](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/))

```
int test(string str) {
    int left = 0, right = 0, ans = 0;
    unordered_set<char> set;
    while(left < str.size() and right < str.size()) {
        if(set.find(str[right]) == set.end()) set.insert(str[right]);
        else {
            while(str[left] != str[right]){
                set.erase(str[left]);
                left++;
            }
            left++;
        }
        right++;
        ans = (ans > set.size() ? ans : set.size());
    }
    return ans;
};
```

What is the time complexity of above solution? Is it O(n^2) or O(n) where n is the length of string?

Please note that I have gone through multiple questions on internet and also read about big oh but I am still confused. To me, it looks like O(n^2) complexity due to two while loops but I want to confirm from experts here.

Comment: appears to be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n) on average.

What you see here is a sliding window technique (with [variable window size, also called "two pointers technique"](https://zengruiwang.medium.com/sliding-window-technique-360d840d5740)).

Yes there are two loops, but if you look, any iteration of any of the two loops will always increase one of the pointers (either `left` or `right`).
In the first loop, either you call the second loop or you don't, but you will increase `right` at each iteration. The second loop always increases `left`.

Both `left` and `right` can have `n` different values (because both loops would stop when either `right >= n` or `left == right`).
So the first loop will have `n` executions (all the values of `right` from `0` to `n-1`) and the second loop can have at most `n` executions (all the possible values of `left`), which is a worst case of `2n = O(n)` executions.

##### Worst case complexity

For the sake of completeness, please note that I wrote O(n) **on average**. The reason is that `set.find` has a [complexity of O(1) in average but O(n) in the worst case](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/). Same goes for [set.erase](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/erase/). The reason is that `unordered_set` is implemented with a hash table and it the very unlikely case of all your items being in the same bucket, it needs to iterate on all the items.

So even though we have O(n) iterations of the loop, some iterations could be O(n). It means that in some **very unlikely** cases, the execution could go up to O(n^2). You shouldn't really worry about it as the probability of this to happen is close to 0, and even though I don't exactly know what the hashing technique for `char` in C++, I would bet that we will never end up with all characters in the same bucket.